# Run a workflow when multiple other workflows have finished in github actions

Tags: github-actions

For example in my repository I have 3 github action workflows: linting(L), unittests(U) and also  build(B) workflow which I want to trigger only when L and U are done.
Both L and U trigger automatically on a push event.
If I do this in B workflow:

```
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Lint", "UnitTests"]
    types: 
      - completed
```

I get my build workflow triggered twice, first time when L finishes and second time when U finishes.
Is it possible to trigger B only once when both L and U have finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible out of the box. It works like `OR` here. If you want to trigger this workflows only when both workflow finished you need to introduce some kind of orchestrator here which will store state and keep information about already executed workflows. It could be some stateful app. However, this is huge effort.

Comment: I got the idea. Then what should we do if there are multiple heavy tasks which we'd like to do in parallel to save some time?

Comment: If you can run them in a single workflow. Put them in a seprate jobs clearing theirs dependency. Add a thrid job which will be dependent of two first. What you get? Job 1st and 2nd will go parallel and 3rd will wait for them. BTW If my answer was helpful, can you also consider upvoting it?

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no nice way of avoiding this, but if the triggering jobs take the same time, you can use the [`concurrency`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency) feature of GitHub Workflows:

```yaml
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

This will avoid running both jobs concurrently and cancel the first one to run, but it depends on the time it takes to complete the trigger workflows. If the run time difference between the triggering workflows is longer than the triggered workflow run time, then it will run twice completely anyway.